# Could not initialize GLX -- CLI on virtual machine

Tags: qt, opengl, virtual-machine

I created a Qt app with a GUI that can also run on the command line (by never calling QMainWindow::show()). When I try to run it on a Debian virtual machine I get the error:

```
$ xvfb-run ./myApp
Could not initialize GLX 
Aborted
```

I built it on Ubuntu 16.04 with dynamic linking to the Qt libs and copied over the needed libraries. It was previously working, but started giving this error after I updated the app. How can I find out if this error is due to missing dependency or some issue with xvfb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely because you instantiate `QApplication` or `QGuiApplication`: not showing the window is not enough. When you run from the command line, you also need to use `QCoreApplication` only.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <memory>
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <io.h>
int isatty(int fd) { return _isatty(fd); }
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

using MyWindow = QWidget;

bool onCommandLine() {
   return isatty(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   std::unique_ptr<QCoreApplication> app(
            onCommandLine() ? new QCoreApplication(argc, argv)
                            : new QApplication(argc, argv));

   /* common logic goes here, e.g. argument parsing, etc. */    

   if (!onCommandLine()) {
      MyWindow w;
      w.show();
      return app->exec();
   } else
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $ xvfb-run ./myApp
> ```

Xvfb doesn't support GLX / OpenGL. That's all. Either use a full blown Xorg server with GPU drivers or a headless EGL context.